# ERROR: Feature 'opengles2' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'config.win32 || (!config.watchos && !features.opengl-desktop && libs.opengl_es2)'failed

Tags: qt, opengl-es, raspberry-pi

Trying to compile qt 5.9 for my raspberry pi 3 compute module and I have been following mainly the online guide here (http://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide). So, I have set the pi system roots to the mount point /mnt/pi-rootfs. 
Please note I m using Raspbian Stretch.

The qtbase configuration was called with the following argument:

```
./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-optionCROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5pi
```

This configures qt but no openGL and I have the message:
ERROR: Feature 'opengles2' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'config.win32 || (!config.watchos && !features.opengl-desktop && libs.opengl_es2)' failed.

ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.

In addition, I also tried to add these 'QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL' to qmake.conf in linux-rasp-pi-g++ but still no sucess.

Please advise how to fix these issues.

Note: Already tried solution recommended in below line but still having the same issue. 
[qt cross compilation for raspberry pi: Cannot find GLESv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639014/qt-cross-compilation-for-raspberry-pi-cannot-find-glesv2)

Comment: I'm on the same journey. I updated my rpi image with 'sudo rpi-update' and saw a bunch of GLES files get generated in the opt/vc folder. My kernel is now 14.14 and in /opt/vc/lib I see libGLESv2.so, etc. Strangely, in my 5.10.1 version of QT, I do not see linux-rasp-pi-g++ in qtbase/mkspecs which could also be an issue. If we can define a mkspec that provides QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `EXTRA_INCLUDEPATH = /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/include` - or wherever your sysroot include path is, at the -xplatform "spec" you are using ( "qtbase/mkspecs/your_spec/qmake.conf").
More info at: "qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_configure.prf"@"qtConfResolvePathIncs".

The above could help for the "configure" part. Good luck with the "build" one.